# Text summarization in R language

Tags: r, text, text-mining, summarization

I have long text file using help of `R language` I want to summarize text in at least 10 to 20 line or in small sentences.
How to summarize text in at least 10 line with `R language` ?

Comment: Please post some sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: Did some online class start today that does text mining? There's been a bunch of new peeps around here asking terrible questions like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this (from the [LSAfun](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LSAfun/index.html) package):

```
genericSummary(D,k=1)
```

whereby 'D' specifies your text document and 'k' the number of sentences to be used in the summary. (Further modifications are shown in the package documentation).

For more information:
http://search.r-project.org/library/LSAfun/html/genericSummary.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a package called [lexRankr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lexRankr/lexRankr.pdf) that summarizes text in the same way that Reddit's /u/autotldr bot summarizes articles. [This article](https://adamspannbauer.github.io/2017/12/17/summarizing-web-articles-with-r/) has a full walkthrough on how to use it but just as a quick example so you can test it yourself in R:

```
#load needed packages
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(lexRankr)

#url to scrape
monsanto_url = "https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2017/sep/28/monsanto-banned-from-european-parliament"

#read page html
page = xml2::read_html(monsanto_url)
#extract text from page html using selector
page_text = rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(page, ".js-article__body p"))

#perform lexrank for top 3 sentences
top_3 = lexRankr::lexRank(page_text,
                          #only 1 article; repeat same docid for all of input vector
                          docId = rep(1, length(page_text)),
                          #return 3 sentences to mimick /u/autotldr's output
                          n = 3,
                          continuous = TRUE)

#reorder the top 3 sentences to be in order of appearance in article
order_of_appearance = order(as.integer(gsub("_","",top_3$sentenceId)))
#extract sentences in order of appearance
ordered_top_3 = top_3[order_of_appearance, "sentence"]

> ordered_top_3
[1] "Monsanto lobbyists have been banned from entering the European parliament after the multinational refused to attend a parliamentary hearing into allegations of regulatory interference."
[2] "Monsanto officials will now be unable to meet MEPs, attend committee meetings or use digital resources on parliament premises in Brussels or Strasbourg."                                
[3] "A Monsanto letter to MEPs seen by the Guardian said that the European parliament was not “an appropriate forum” for discussion on the issues involved."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach based on the Pegasus transformer model :

```
library(reticulate)

conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "summary") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "summary", packages = c("transformers", "SentencePiece"), python_version = "3.9.16")
  reticulate::conda_install(envname = "summary", packages = "torch", pip = TRUE)
}  

reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "summary")
transformers <- import(module = "transformers")

tokenizer <- transformers$AutoTokenizer$from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
model <- transformers$PegasusForConditionalGeneration$from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")

summarize <- function(text)
{
  inputs <- tokenizer(text, return_tensors = "pt")
  output_sequences <- model$generate(input_ids = inputs$input_ids)
  summarized_text <- tokenizer$batch_decode(output_sequences)
  return(summarized_text)
}

text <-  "Monsanto lobbyists have been banned from entering the European parliament after the multinational refused to attend a\n 
          parliamentary hearing into allegations of regulatory interference.\n
          It is the first time MEPs have used new rules to withdraw parliamentary access for firms that ignore\n
          a summons to attend parliamentary inquiries or hearings.\n
          Monsanto officials will now be unable to meet MEPs, attend committee meetings or use digital resources on parliament premises in Brussels or Strasbourg.\n
          While a formal process still needs to be worked through, a spokesman for the parliament’s president Antonio Tajani said that\n
          the leaders of all major parliamentary blocks had backed the ban in a vote this morning."
        
summarize(text)

[1] "<pad> MEPs have taken the first step in blocking access to the European Parliament for lobbying firms.</s>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered based on chatGPT :

```
library(chatgpt)
question <- "Can you summarize the following text in one sentence : \n Monsanto lobbyists have been banned from entering the European parliament after the multinational refused to attend a\n 
             parliamentary hearing into allegations of regulatory interference.\n
             It is the first time MEPs have used new rules to withdraw parliamentary access for firms that ignore\n
             a summons to attend parliamentary inquiries or hearings.\n
             Monsanto officials will now be unable to meet MEPs, attend committee meetings or use digital resources on parliament premises in Brussels or Strasbourg.\n
             While a formal process still needs to be worked through, a spokesman for the parliament’s president Antonio Tajani said that\n
             the leaders of all major parliamentary blocks had backed the ban in a vote this morning."

Sys.setenv(OPENAI_API_KEY = "xxx")
chatgpt::reset_chat_session()
ask_chatgpt(question)

[1] "Monsanto lobbyists have been banned from the European parliament for refusing to attend a hearing on allegations of regulatory interference, marking the first time new rules have been used to withdraw parliamentary access from firms that ignore summons to attend inquiries or hearings."
```