# Abstractive text summary in R

Tags: r, text, nlp, summarization

This is a short question.

Is there a way to perform abstractive text summarization in R?

There are ways to perform extractive summary (ie extract few relevant sentences), as shown here [Text summarization in R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064946/text-summarization-in-r-language)

However, I was unable to find a way to do abstractive summary "purely" in R. I understand that abstractive summary is way more complex and typically requires model training. The two methods that might work so far are using python through `reticulate` package or use on of google's APIs. was wondering if anyone is aware of R package that does that without external dependencies.

thank you in advance